# Why are Plasma child chains forced to be of UTXO type, and why not a regular ethereum chain running PoA or similar?

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-development, sidechain, plasma, poa

Been doing research in Plasma, and Ethereum side chains and something I've come across (but can't seem to find an explanation of) is why are all  Plasma child chains of UTXO type?

I'm wondering why not use child chains that aren't UTXO? Wouldn't it be possible to just build a PoA or other type of Ethereum network and broadcast the blocks to contracts on the mainchain?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, plasma is trying to minimise storage and logic. With a UTXO-based sidechain, the bitmap can directly represent txs bit by bit. They do mention in the white paper that it is possible to still do it state-based but it would increase the logic behind it.

Answer (score 2):

The UTXO model is for starting on the Minimal Viable Plasma. This is so that it is much easier to implement, than an account based model like in an ethereum chain, in terms of security mechanism of plasma, which I think is what the MVP is focusing on. Yes, the idea eventually is to implement general state transitions on the child chain like on ethereum, but I would assume there are more things to think about security there, with exit mechanisms n all, than can be implemented in an MVP.

Learn and contribute to plasma [here](https://www.learnplasma.org)

[About plasma MVP](https://www.learnplasma.org/docs/plasma-mvp.html)

Comment: There is more reliance on the root chain if an account-based model is chosen. The goal is to let the Plasma child-chain be as much self-sufficient as possible, and UTXOs help in doing so.

Comment: Please add some sources/links and I will mark this as the answer.

Comment: Have added a link that has more info on plasma.I would say, the focus initially is more on getting the security and exit mechanism right, in enabling a user at any level to have a safe exit on its parent chain, up to the the ethereum chain.